# How to use map created in TileMill software along with mapbox.js

Tags: mapbox

I am very new to [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/). My requirement is create map with custom colors. So I created map using TileMill  Software. Now I want to use that map with [mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api).

In example of mapbox.js API I reviewed code this

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-2k9d7u0c') <<--
    .setView([38.89399, -77.03659], 13);
```

Is there any option to replace **"examples.map-2k9d7u0c"** to load my map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you'll need to

- Create a [Mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/) account.
- [Authorize and upload your map](https://www.mapbox.com/help/design-upload-custom-layers-from-tilemill/)
- [Find the Map ID in your account on Mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-id/)